# The current subscription type is not permitted to perform operations on any provider namespace

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I am able to login to azure via Azure CLI and after it listed subscription I have access to after that I am providing this command "az vm image list --all -f GitHub-Enterprise" and I am getting the error "The current subscription type is not permitted to perform operations on any provider namespace".
Pls help me with this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following command:

```
az account set -subscription <Subscription ID>
```

Then run the following to check which providers are registered:

```
az provider list --query "[].{Provider:namespace, Status:registrationState}" --out table
```

To register a resource provider, use the az provider register command, e.g.:

```
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Compute
```

To register all available providers try

```
az provider list --query "[].namespace" -o tsv | ForEach-Object { az provider register -n $_}
```

Note if new resource providers are added you will have to re-run that command

Comment: Can you explain me about the resource providers and why it was restricting me from listing the images from CLI ?